# How to set app icon between home indicater icon and app title on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[This is my Action Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKLJb.png) i wanna set app icon between arrow and activity title so please tell me how to achieve this OR instead of acivity title i can set app icon there? 
Please tell me how to achieve this.

i have used this code to do so.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification1);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
```

Comment: check this example: http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

Comment: @AntonKovalyov Is there any option without customizing action bar.?

Comment: @AntonKovalyov How does flip kart do same?

Answer (score 0):

In code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.layout_actionbar);
```

In layout folder make layout_actionbar.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView />
    <TextView />

</LinearLayout>
```

The back arrow should remain in place, in imageview add your icon and in text view your text.

Comment: Is there any option without customizing action bar.?

Comment: How does flip kart do same?